# Excel, Many to Many Relationship, Value Rollup: Add Multiple Values Based on Parent/Child Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, many-to-many, parent-child

**TLDR: I need help trying to index a set or multiple values of data from another sheet based off of a parent/child criteria in the current sheet**

I am looking to roll up values based on a parent child relationship. I can currently roll up values for a single row, but not for a set of data from another sheet. In my scenario, a parent may also be a child, requiring that row to be rolled up into its parent value as well.

My current data sets include a parent/child link table (including quantities) and a static data set in another sheet. I would prefer to keep the static data set as is (without calculated values) for easier import/ export and adding/ removing data.

In my parent/child data set, the "hours" column, gathers the values of multiple columns from the "data" sheet, adds them together, and multiplies them by the quantity with the formula:

```
=SUM((data!$C$2:$F$99999)*(--(data!$A$2:$A$99999=B2))*C2)
```

This formula works well for gathering the data for the specified cell, but the child data needs added to this as well. I have done that with this formula in the "TL hours" column, but ideally these would be all part of one formula and only grab the data from the "data" sheet instead of using the calculated value in the "hours" column:

```
=SUM((data!$C$2:$F$99999)*(--(data!$A$2:$A$99999=B2)*C2),IF(A:A=B2,D:D,0))
```

What I am wanting to be able to do is for every parent, it indexes its own data and then searched the "parent" column for any matches. If matches exist, index the data of all children and add them to the parent value to get a rolled up value of everything included in the parent. My current issue is that I cannot get it to index multiple row values based on the fact that it is a child of another row.

EDIT:

| Parent | ingredient | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| white almond cupcake | white almond cake | .5 |
| white almond cake | flour | 10 |
| white almond cake | water | 1 |
| white almond cake | egg whites | 5 |
| white almond cake | sugar | 5 |
| white almond cake | almond extract | 1 |
| white cake | flour | 10 |
| white cake | water | 1 |
| white cake | egg whites | 5 |
| white cake | sugar | 5 |

| item | purchase price | movement hours | prep hours | mix hours | bake hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| white almond cake | 0 | .1 | .5 | .1 | .25 |
| white cake | 0 | .1 | .5 | .1 | .25 |
| white almond cupcake | 0 | .1 | .5 | .1 | .25 |
| almond extract | 20 | .5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| flour | .5 | .5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| water | .1 | .5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| egg whites | .75 | .5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Which Excel version are you working with? Could you please provide your input data as table - then it is much easier to help you (you can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables for that)

Comment: @Ike I am using office and excel 365.. I was able to get it to work in a way using an index match, but its a bit clunky since it return the sum of the columns, so I have to specify each column and add them together; formula below:

Comment: =SUM((data!$C$2:$F$9999)*(--(data!$A$2:$A$9999=B2)),IF($B2=$A$2:$A$9999,INDEX(data!$C$2:$F$9999,MATCH($B$2:$B$9999,data!$A$2:$A$9999,0),1),""),IF($B2=$A$2:$A$9999,INDEX(data!$C$2:$F$9999,MATCH($B$2:$B$9999,data!$A$2:$A$9999,0),2),""),IF($B2=$A$2:$A$9999,INDEX(data!$C$2:$F$9999,MATCH($B$2:$B$9999,data!$A$2:$A$9999,0),3),""),IF($B2=$A$2:$A$9999,INDEX(data!$C$2:$F$9999,MATCH($B$2:$B$9999,data!$A$2:$A$9999,0),4),""))